# shopify single product colour swatches that use links, not variants

Tags: shopify

I'm currently working on a Shopify project and I need to add color swatches on the product pages. I already did it in other projects using the product variants. But in this case the colors are different products. I found some examples on shopify:

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post source code and add details about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i try to  one  apps and its working  fine (product-colors)